# Temp table ,is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, procedure, proc

I'm new to SQL already researched in the Chinese do not think swimming on my mistake

```
    DECLARE @Temp_Table TABLE 
    (
        ID_CLIENTE nvarchar(50),
        ID_ATENDENTE nvarchar(50),
         EQUIPE_VENDA nvarchar(50),
         NOME nvarchar(255)
    )


INSERT INTO @Temp_Table
      SELECT DISTINCT  Lig.ID_CLIENTE ,Vend.ID_ATENDENTE,Vend.EQUIPE_VENDA,Vend.NOME
      FROM [TB_AGENDA-VENDEDOR_LIGACOES] as Lig 
         INNER JOIN [TB_AGENDA-VENDEDOR_VENDEDORES] as Vend
            ON Vend.ID_ATENDENTE = Lig.ID_ATENDENTE 
       ORDER BY Lig.ID_CLIENTE

SELECT count(*),ID_CLIENTE,EQUIPE_VENDA,NOME FROM @Temp_Table GROUP BY ID_ATENDENTE


I have 2 tables, first take the repetitions example:
Line 1: 1 user | 1 adm | 20/02/2015
Line 2: 1 user | 1 adm | 24/02/2015
Line 3: 2 user | adm 1 | 03.30.2015
Row 4: 3 user | adm 2 | 20.04.2015

end
Line 1: 1 user | 1 adm | 24/02/2015
Line 2: 2 user | adm 1 | 03.30.2015
Line 3: 3 user | adm 2 | 20.04.2015

then I want to group by ADM's

adm 1 count 2
adm 2 count 1
```

Column '@Temp_Table.ID_CLIENTE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's very unclear what your are attempting to ask here

Comment: 'I have 2 tables, first take the repetitions example:

Line 1: 1 user | 1 adm | 20/02/2015
Line 2: 1 user | 1 adm | 24/02/2015
Line 3: 2 user | adm 1 | 03.30.2015
Row 4: 3 user | adm 2 | 20.04.2015

end
Line 1: 1 user | 1 adm | 24/02/2015
Line 2: 2 user | adm 1 | 03.30.2015
Line 3: 3 user | adm 2 | 20.04.2015

then I want to group by ADM's

adm 1 count 2
adm 2 count 1'

Comment: Just curious, what do you mean by "I'm new to SQL already researched in the Chinese do not think swimming on my mistake"?

Comment: Is there some reason why the error message you are getting isn't the answer to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query is wrong:

```
SELECT count(*), ID_CLIENTE, EQUIPE_VENDA, NOME
FROM @Temp_Table
GROUP BY ID_ATENDENTE;
```

Either you want:

```
SELECT count(*), ID_ATENDENTE
FROM @Temp_Table
GROUP BY ID_ATENDENTE;
```

or:

```
SELECT count(*), ID_CLIENTE, EQUIPE_VENDA, NOME
FROM @Temp_Table
GROUP BY ID_CLIENTE, EQUIPE_VENDA, NOME;
```

Or perhaps something else.